# How to incorporate spatial correlation function into Linear mixed effect model in Matlab?

Tags: correlation, mixed-model, matlab, spatial

I have spatially correlated data which I want to fit in a linear mixed effect model In matlab. I use fitlmematrix model where there are only one co-variance structure to be included which is for random errors. I want to incorporate error variance as a guassian correlation function but could not find any source about how to do so. Any help would be appropriated. My code is given below:

```
load(fullfile(matlabroot,'examples','stats','weight.mat'));
```

Fit a linear mixed-effects model, where miles per gallon (MPG) is the response, weight is the predictor variable, and the intercept varies by model year. First, define the design matrices. Then, fit the model using the specified design matrices.

```
Subject = nominal(Subject);
Program = nominal(Program);
D = dummyvar(Program); % Create dummy variables for Program
X = [ones(120,1), InitialWeight, D(:,2:4), Week,...
     D(:,2).*Week, D(:,3).*Week, D(:,4).*Week];
Z = [ones(120,1), Week];
G = Subject;
```

Fit the model using fitlmematrix with the defined design matrices and grouping variables.

```
lme = fitlmematrix(X,y,Z,G,'Covariancepattern','Isotropic')
```

The co-variance pattern above I think is for random effect variance not for the error variance.